timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online android studio error
I'm facing an issue where my Android emulator shows a black screen for 5-7 minutes on startup:

I've tried restarting the emulator, updating Android Studio, and adjusting RAM settings, but nothing seems to help. My setup includes, Android Studio, and the latest emulator version. Any advice on how to fix this?
Details:
OS: [Windows 11]
Android Studio: [[Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-241.18034.62.2411.12169540, built on August 1, 2024 Runtime version: 17.0.11+0--11852314 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. Windows 11.0 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 2]]
Emulator: [2.7 QVGA API 34 Android 14 "upsideDownCake" |x 86_64 ]


Does this only happen on the latest API level on an emulated device? Or does it happen on any emulated device you create?


Setting the Graphics option on the Android Virtual Device to Software instead of Automatic or Hardware.

Quit Android studio and launch terminal. Run these commands:
adb kill-server
adb forward --remove-all
adb start-server 


Go to Device Manager (Tools -> Device Manager) -> Wipe the data of your device and try starting it again.

Now you can launch Android Studio and try again.



So what is the point of HW acceleration if you can't use it ?
